# WCF SOAP service returns 404 Not Found for HTTPS endpoint

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I got .NET 4.5 WCF service hosted in IIS 8.5 on domain `https://mydomain`, with https binding and self signed certificate configured in IIS.

I can access the configuration page of my service in browser on `https://mydomain/FileService.svc`

When I try to `POST` some data to the service using SoapUI to the endpoint `https://mydomain/FileService.svc/receiveRequest`, I get back `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

My web.config service configuration looks as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <!-- maxReceivedMessageSize = 1073741824 = 1 GB -->
      <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" >
        <security mode="None"></security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
  </protocolMapping>

  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <services>

    <service name="Foo.FileService">
      <endpoint contract="IFileService" binding="basicHttpBinding"></endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Any idea how to solve this or get some more information for further debugging?
Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I have tested the service on my **dev** machine. It was deployed on `http://localhost` and the call from SoapUI worked. I used `http://localhost/FileService.svc/receiveRequest` to call the service endpoint and it responded with `200` and SOAP message.

**EDIT 2**

When accessing the WCF service endpoint `http://mydomain/FileService.svc/receiveRequest` on my **test** machine without `HTTPS` it works.

Comment: Did you try with some get operation too? Looks like IIS is not responding to your post request. Go to IIS Manager, in home open request filtering - http verbs and check out if post is not denied. Usually this tab is empty, but you can add post verb to test.

Comment: Why do you post to `/receiveRequest`?

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual: `Request filtering` is empty, so I tried to deny `POST` verb and got back different error - `HTTP Error 404.6 - Not Found`, so I think `POST` verb is not denied.

Comment: @CodeCaster: My `FileService` class implements interface `IFileService` `ServiceContract`, which has `OperationContract` method `receiveRequest`, therefore I am using `/receiveRequest` to tell the service which operation to invoke.

Comment: Yeah but  that's not how SOAP works. Omit the `/receiverequest`. The operation is specified in the SOAPAction header.

Comment: @CodeCaster removed `/receiverequest` from URL, but still getting `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

Comment: There can be many things wrong here. Why don't you test it locally with the WCF Test Client? You will need to elimintate the defect component, we can only give hints.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have tested the service on my dev machine. It was deployed on `http://localhost` and the call from SoapUI worked. I used `http://localhost/FileService.svc/receiveRequest` to call the service endpoint and it responded with `200` and SOAP message.

Comment: Well that would be very valuable information to [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally cracked it! I was missing binding for `HTTPS` endpoint, where `security` mode can not be set to `None`.

This is updated configuration for bindings:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="myHttpsBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824">
    <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
    </security>
  </binding>

  <binding name="myHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824">
    <security mode="None" />
  </binding>    
</basicHttpBinding>
```

This is updated configuration for service endpoints:

```
<service name="Foo.FileService">
  <!-- HTTPS Endpoint -->
  <endpoint contract="IFileService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myHttpsBinding" ></endpoint>
  <!-- HTTP Endpoint -->
  <endpoint contract="IFileService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myHttpBinding" ></endpoint>
</service>
```

And now both endpoints `http://mydomain/FileService.svc/receiveRequest` and `https://mydomain/FileService.svc/receiveRequest` work for me.

Comment: You saved me brother! Thank you!