# Endpoint Not Found Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, winforms-interop

Does anyone have any idea about the error shown here?

Local IIS is working fine, but after hosting on the production server, I am getting this error:

> EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://webpalm-srv-cld/HTTPS_2/SredniaService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: Did you check the `InnerException`? What did it tell you?¨

Comment: I read your previous post and here you mentioned that the problem only appears on IIS. So I think the address of your endpoint needs to be written with an absolute address, you can try my method. This is because when hosting a WCF service on IIS, you can only use the base address of the URL to the .svc file as the base address. If you specify any other base addresses, they will be ignored.

Comment: Probably needs to be `https://` not `http://`. Port 80 might not even have a binding in production.

Comment: i had change default port and https port. 443

Comment: I found a post that describes a similar issue to yours and is using the same version. I think you can refer to this:[WCF SOAP service returns 404 Not Found for HTTPS endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609836/wcf-soap-service-returns-404-not-found-for-https-endpoint)